# Pandas - Calculating Average of Field and Multiply By Number of Occurrences

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, mean

Here is a data frame. I want to calculate the average ratio of play type(short_pass, long_pass, deep_pass) and multiply it by how often the play_type occurred.

I can do a group_by play_type and get individual mean, but am stuck on getting the number of times a play_type occurred( short pass occurs twice) and then multiplying the two.

Thanks!

```
Quarterback   Play_Type Ratio

Brady   Short_Pass    5.4
Brady   Long_Pass     7.2
Brady   Deep_Pass     8.1
Rodgers Long_Pass     6.4
Rodgers Deep_Pass     7.2
Miller  Short_Pass    4.2
Miller  Deep_Pass     7.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
g = df.groupby('Play_Type')
g.Ratio.mean() * g.Play_Type.count()

Play_Type
Deep_Pass     22.6
Long_Pass     13.6
Short_Pass     9.6
dtype: float64
```

---

However, this is the same as the `sum`

```
g = df.groupby('Play_Type')
g.Ratio.sum()

Play_Type
Deep_Pass     22.6
Long_Pass     13.6
Short_Pass     9.6
Name: Ratio, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to do with multiple groupby statements This is much clearer. Have a great night!